# when i scroll tableview data is not displaying in proper way

Tags: ios, nsindexpath, uitableview

I am building iOS App using StoryBoards.

I have a tableview.

In tableview Cell ,i created 5 buttons and a label programmatically.

In the button Action i increase the size of the selected button and make the other buttons as the default size.

For the 1st 4 cells it working fine.when i added new cell data is coming.

The problem occur when i scrolls the tableview,the buttons and labels in the cells are displaying not in the order.Wrong data is displayed.

cell state of the tableview is changing.

Here is my code.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *Cellidentifier1 = @"identifier";

    cell1 = [_skillSelectionTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Cellidentifier1 forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell1.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

 first[indexPath.row] = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

            first[indexPath.row].frame = CGRectMake(75, 40, 40, 20);

            [first[indexPath.row] setTitle:@"first1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [first[indexPath.row] setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0f green:210.0/255.0f blue:186.0/255.0f alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];



            first[indexPath.row].backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0f green:210.0/255.0f blue:186.0/255.0f  alpha:1.0];

            [first[indexPath.row] addTarget:self action:@selector(increaseAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            first[indexPath.row].tag = indexPath.row;

            [cell1.contentView addSubview: first
[indexPath.row]];

           Second[indexPath.row] = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

            Second[indexPath.row].frame = CGRectMake(120, 40, 40, 20);

            [Second[indexPath.row] setTitle:@"Second1
" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [Second[indexPath.row] setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0f green:190.0/255.0f blue:176.0/255.0f alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            Second[indexPath.row].backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0f green:190.0/255.0f blue:176.0/255.0f  alpha:1.0];

            [Second[indexPath.row] addTarget:self action:@selector(increaseAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            Second[indexPath.row].tag = indexPath.row;

            [cell1.contentView addSubview:second[indexPath.row]];

           third[indexPath.row] = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

            third[indexPath.row].frame = CGRectMake(160, 35, 50, 30);

            [third[indexPath.row] setTitle:@"third 
1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [third[indexPath.row] setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0f green:180.0/255.0f blue:166.0/255.0f alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            third[indexPath.row].backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0f green:180.0/255.0f blue:166.0/255.0f  alpha:1.0];

            [third[indexPath.row] addTarget:self action:@selector(increaseAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            third[indexPath.row].tag = indexPath.row;

            [cell1.contentView addSubview: third
[indexPath.row]];

            label[indexPath.row] = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 69, 200, 21)];

             label[indexPath.row].text=@"second";

   label[indexPath.row].textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;

[cell1.contentView addSubview:label[indexPath.row]];

    return cell1;

}


-(IBAction)increaseAction:(id)sender

{

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *) sender;

    if ([[button currentTitle] isEqualToString:@“First1"])

    {

       First[button.tag].frame = CGRectMake(70, 35, 50, 30);

        second[button.tag].frame = CGRectMake(120, 40, 40, 20);

       third[button.tag].frame = CGRectMake(165, 40, 40, 20);

        label[button.tag].text=@"First";

}

    if ([[button currentTitle] isEqualToString:@"second1"])

    {

        First[button.tag].frame = CGRectMake(75, 40, 40, 20);

        second[button.tag].frame = CGRectMake(115, 35, 50, 30);

        third[button.tag].frame = CGRectMake(165, 40, 40, 20);

        label[button.tag].text=@"second";

    }

    if ([[button currentTitle] isEqualToString:@"third1"])

    {

        First[button.tag].frame = CGRectMake(75, 40, 40, 20);

        second[button.tag].frame = CGRectMake(120, 40, 40, 20);

        third[button.tag].frame = CGRectMake(160, 35, 50, 30);

        label[button.tag].text=@"third";

}

}
```

Comment: i tried that.No change.Please help me.

Comment: this is happen because of the static identifier your cell are reused.

Comment: So how can we change that.

Comment: try with costume cell

Comment: I am a starter in iOS.1st time i am hearing about costume cell.I will search and apply.

Comment: its not costume cell, its custom cell..lol

Comment: @Sudhi9135 search for some UITableView Tutorials and read that..That will help you understand..what mistake you are making with cell reuse.

Comment: ohh sorry about my english i am in rush at that time

Comment: @chirag Its okay.No problem

Comment: @Kundan all are working fine until scrolls.Middle cells have no problem.Its not reusing

Comment: @Sudhi9135 its an issue of reusing and i am confident about that..So i have suggested..btw it your wish.

Comment: @Kundan .May be you are right.I told that middle cells are okay.Its remain constant

Comment: @Sudhi9135 i told you in the begining only..

Comment: @kundan give me your email_id.i will sent the sample project.

Comment: Sorry can't share the email..You Upload the project on sendspace.com and share the link.

Comment: https://www.sendspace.com/file/5vat7x

Comment: Above is the link and its a sample project.

Comment: @Kundan Let me know do you have any confusions.

Comment: 3 buttons we have.1,2,3 when we click 1,It must enlarge others must remain the default size.similarly in the case of 2 and 3.select different buttons and scrolls 2 or 3 times.click the buttons on the last rows.After scrolling we can make the 3 buttons at a time bigger.Its incorrect.Only one button must be highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this issue is about cell reuse properly. So, edited your code and its working fine now.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSString * Cellidentifier1 = [NSString
                                    stringWithFormat:@"identifier %ld",(long)indexPath.row];

    cell1 = [_skillSelectionTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Cellidentifier1];

    cell1.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

 first[indexPath.row] = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

            first[indexPath.row].frame = CGRectMake(75, 40, 40, 20);

            [first[indexPath.row] setTitle:@"first1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [first[indexPath.row] setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0f green:210.0/255.0f blue:186.0/255.0f alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];



            first[indexPath.row].backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0f green:210.0/255.0f blue:186.0/255.0f  alpha:1.0];

            [first[indexPath.row] addTarget:self action:@selector(increaseAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            first[indexPath.row].tag = indexPath.row;

            [cell1.contentView addSubview: first
[indexPath.row]];

           Second[indexPath.row] = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

            Second[indexPath.row].frame = CGRectMake(120, 40, 40, 20);

            [Second[indexPath.row] setTitle:@"Second1
" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [Second[indexPath.row] setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0f green:190.0/255.0f blue:176.0/255.0f alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            Second[indexPath.row].backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0f green:190.0/255.0f blue:176.0/255.0f  alpha:1.0];

            [Second[indexPath.row] addTarget:self action:@selector(increaseAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            Second[indexPath.row].tag = indexPath.row;

            [cell1.contentView addSubview:second[indexPath.row]];

           third[indexPath.row] = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

            third[indexPath.row].frame = CGRectMake(160, 35, 50, 30);

            [third[indexPath.row] setTitle:@"third 
1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [third[indexPath.row] setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0f green:180.0/255.0f blue:166.0/255.0f alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            third[indexPath.row].backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0f green:180.0/255.0f blue:166.0/255.0f  alpha:1.0];

            [third[indexPath.row] addTarget:self action:@selector(increaseAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            third[indexPath.row].tag = indexPath.row;

            [cell1.contentView addSubview: third
[indexPath.row]];

            label[indexPath.row] = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 69, 200, 21)];

             label[indexPath.row].text=@"second";

   label[indexPath.row].textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;

[cell1.contentView addSubview:label[indexPath.row]];

    return cell1;

}


-(IBAction)increaseAction:(id)sender

{

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *) sender;

    if ([[button currentTitle] isEqualToString:@“First1"])

    {

       First[button.tag].frame = CGRectMake(70, 35, 50, 30);

        second[button.tag].frame = CGRectMake(120, 40, 40, 20);

       third[button.tag].frame = CGRectMake(165, 40, 40, 20);

        label[button.tag].text=@"First";

}

    if ([[button currentTitle] isEqualToString:@"second1"])

    {

        First[button.tag].frame = CGRectMake(75, 40, 40, 20);

        second[button.tag].frame = CGRectMake(115, 35, 50, 30);

        third[button.tag].frame = CGRectMake(165, 40, 40, 20);

        label[button.tag].text=@"second";

    }

    if ([[button currentTitle] isEqualToString:@"third1"])

    {

        First[button.tag].frame = CGRectMake(75, 40, 40, 20);

        second[button.tag].frame = CGRectMake(120, 40, 40, 20);

        third[button.tag].frame = CGRectMake(160, 35, 50, 30);

        label[button.tag].text=@"third";

}

}
```

Enjoy!!

Comment: But there is an exception,unable to dequeue a cell with identifier identifier 0 - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: In the sample project that i have sent you i dont create cell in xib.so i dont need to specify the cell identifier

Comment: Now there is another exception,'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

Comment: That not working.Because of that.I will vote for you.sure.Please help me.I am a beginner in iOS.I want to solve this

Comment: Overwriting problem is solved.But when i scrolls the tableview only the third button is highlighted.Its happens only when i scrolls speedly.other wise i am getting the data perfectly.

Comment: Try deselectRowAtIndexPath in cellforrowatindexpath..hope solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find your  init code for the cell,did you forget creating the cell before reusing it

```
 cell1 = [_skillSelectionTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Cellidentifier1 forIndexPath:indexPath];
if(!cell1){
cell1 = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]  initnitWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier
}
....
```

Comment: I Applied your code its not working.the same problem appears when scrolls.